# "provided that there be" vs. "provided that there is"

Tags: conditionals

Which sentence is grammatically correct? "Be" or "is"?

> Retail stores for the sale of goods are allowed in this zone provided that there **BE** no outside display, storage, or sale of goods without a special permit.

Or

> Retail stores for the sale of goods are allowed in this zone provided that there **IS** no outside display, storage, or sale of goods without a special permit.

I see the "be" usage frequently when reading zoning ordinances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Huddleston & Pullum (2002), using the subjunctive with words like *provided that* (as in "provided that there be") is valid, but rare; they say that "it belongs to formal style and verges on the archaic" (p. 1000). Of course, such formal and old-fashioned constructions are much more common in legal writing than in other contexts, where "provided that there is" would be much more idiomatic.

Comment: So, laughed into court.

Comment: Thank you @alphabet!